# Booking tickets separately

Tags: transit, tickets, layovers, malaysia

I plan to visit the Philippines this August. The direct flights from Colombo to Manila are quite expensive. [AirAsia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airasia) has flights from Colombo but they are a point-to-point carrier. They do not have any tickets that I can buy to fly from Colombo-Kuala Lumpur-Manila. They do have Colombo-Kuala Lumpur and Kuala Lumpur - Manila tickets.

If I have one day for the transit (17 hours) how safe it is to go with separate tickets?

I know it becomes my responsibility to arrange alternative transport in case of a delay, but is it safe if I have a day?

I will need to exit the airport because there is a sleep over, but arrival and departure will be from same airport.

Both flights are two hours each. They have web check-ins. I will be carrying  luggage. I will have nothing to declare in Customs.

- If there are no direct flights, and the available single ticket
  offers are significantly expensive, would you consider traveling with
  two tickets?
- Are there any laws against it, at least any country-specific rules?

Comment: What do you mean how safe? If you have the appropriate visa for Malaysia and are willing to collect and recheck in your luggage, I don't see a problem at all? Why would there be laws against it?

Comment: If AirAsia were to cancel your first flight for some reason, how long until the next one? If it's only once a day, then that's more of an issue than if they fly a few times a day

Comment: @AdityaSomani Yes I have a valid visa to both countries. I thought there could be some regulations that prevents AirAsia from offering a direct flight in first place. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Gagravarr They actually have only one flight a day. However it seems (http://www.flightstats.com/go/Airline/airlineScorecard.do?airlineCode=AK) they hardly cancel a flight. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your particular situation I would be very comfortable travelling with two separate AirAsia tickets from Colombo to Kuala Lumpur to Manila.

There are no rules I am aware of against this.

However, in Kuala Lumpur make sure your transportation takes you to the low cost carrier terminal (LCCT) and not the main terminal. If you go by taxi telling the taxi driver, "AirAsia" should ensure you get to the right location.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I'm kinda hacking the booking process so I'm a little nervous about potential problems. Thanks about the transportation tip as well. Mentioning "Air Asia" will make sense for them rather than telling KLIA/LCCT.