# Can I book two tickets to reach my destination with a stop over to my destination?

Tags: visas, air-travel, tickets, study

I have to go to Toronto from New Delhi. My question is:

Can I book two different tickets for my journey, with 2 different airline?

I might have to check-out and then check-in.

For example can I book a ticket from Delhi to Dublin for one particular date and same day another ticket from Dublin to Toronto?

I'm on Student visa.

Comment: is your question more about the visa aspect? indeed you would need a visa for dublin, or at least to transit dublin.  (sorry, i have no idea what the situation is for Indian passport holders, to, either visit or transit Dublin)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34009/444

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30285/444

Comment: I feel like the Question Asker may be confused about flying on two different airlines to reach a destination.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26780/444

Comment: You can book whatever tickets you want. And it's quite common to book flights on different airlines to get to a final destination. Are you asking if airlines have rules against this? (No, they don't) Or are you asking, as @JoeBlow mentions, about visa requirements? Are you asking which web site allows you to make the purchase? Please clarify your question for us so we can better help you.

Comment: @JoeBlow He doesn't need a transit visa if he is and Indian national. http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html

Comment: Hi Vagish, excellent info.

Answer (score 2):

You can book two separate tickets for two separate flights. However if one flight is delayed and you miss the other you may not be re booked onto the next flight without paying a fee.

Most major airlines will rebook you on for free if they ticketed both parts of the journey. So it is better to see if you can get one airline to ticket the whole journey, this doesn't mean you will fly with just one airline as they can also ticket for partner airlines. For example when I flew to Windsor, Canada I booked the whole journey through British Airways. I flew London to Toronto on British Airways and Toronto to Windsor on Air Canada, my British Airways flight was delayed and I missed the Air Canada one. British Airways then rebooked me free of charge and put me on the next Air Canada flight. That is the benefit of having one airline ticket the whole journey even though I flew two different airlines.

You also don't need a transit visa for Dublin as an Indian national: http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it's almost never a good idea, so you have to have a really good reason to try it. Here are the problems

1. As Vagish pointed out, if there is any delay on your incoming flight, you will miss your connection and the second air line will treat this as your fault. Most will charge you a change fee plus potentially any difference in ticket prices which can be substantial since you are in essence buying a new ticket on short notice. If your miss a connection on a single itinerary, the air line will re-book you free of charge, absorb any price differences in tickets and put you up in a hotel overnight, if that's necessary. In the two airline scenario you are on your own for all of these.
2. When arriving you have to fully clear customs and immigration. So you need a full entry Visa (transit Visa may not be enough) and collect all your bags. The problem is that you need to go to the check in counter of the second airline, which typically is in Ireland proper and not in the transit area
3. Different airlines use different terminals and sometimes even different airports (happened to me in New York once) so there can be a fair bit of extra transportation (with all your bags in tow).
4. It's typically way more expensive.

So you need to have a really good reason to do this, make sure you have all the right Visa and immigration documents for BOTH the final destination and transit country and you need LOTS and LOTS of time for making the connection. 6 hours minimum, I'd say. 8 hours would be safer.

Comment: Sometimes it works out a lot cheaper, but I found that the discount airlines sometimes don't have gates with access to the transit areas forcing tedious encounters with immigration (even if no visa is required). I'll go through a bit of hassle (no extra time in my case) to save a couple hundred dollars, but it's not worth it for everyone.